# mvc does not pick up my parameter values from url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

```
context.Routes.Add(new DomainRoute(domain.DomainExpression, "{language}/{action}/{*urlPath}", new
{
    controller = "Routing",
    action = "Index",
    language = domain.WebsiteDefaultLanguageCulture,
    defaultLanguageName = domain.WebsiteDefaultLanguageCulture,
    sitenumber = domain.WebiteUniqueRefNumber
}));
```

What happened sis the controller RoutingController.Index() is always called regardless of my {action} parameter defined in the route.  What's even worse is that neither {language} nor {*urlPath} can be picked from RouteData.Values - only defaul values are defined i the RouteData.Values

Anyone can help to explain this?  thank you.

Comment: What is your `domain.DomainExpression `?

Comment: hi that was the custom domain section that I created for the application - no worry, problem was caused by a very very very stupid mistake of overriding parameter values by default values...  thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble solved. - It was because the custom route i created "DomainRoute"  where I 'proactively' updated defaults there.

sorted now.

Cheers.